# Empty <title> element in HTML stops HTML from loading if written as <title />

Tags: html

Probably a really dumb question - but in an HTML document, why does the following:

```
 <title></title>
```

work ok (according to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic)

but then

```
<title />
```

will stop the HTML from rendering?

Thanks

Comment: Because `<title>` is a wrapping element so it's expected that it will wrap some content. Therefore there must be a opening and closing tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<title>` tag **must** have a start and an end tag, [it's required](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/title.html):

> #### Tag omission
>
> A title element must have both a start tag and an end tag.

Comment: Thanks - thought I was going mad. Problem is I have been translating my HTML to/from XML and the empty title got 'shortened'.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element):

> The title element must not be empty.

It also states:

> Note: If it's reasonable for the Document to have no title, then the title element is probably not required.

Comment: The quoted text is from a draft that says: “This is a draft document and may be updated, replaced or obsoleted by other documents at any time. It is inappropriate to cite this document as other than work in progress.” And while it is a good principle to have some content in a `title` element, that’s not what the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

In an HTML document delivered as text/html, as web pages normally are, the tag `<title />` is processed by browsers as if the slash were not there. That is, it is just the start tag. And the content of `title` is parsed as text – character references/entities are recognized but no markup, except the element’s own end tag. So all the rest will be taken as the content of the `title` element, leaving no visible content to render.

Formally, `<title />` is invalid in all forms of HTML up to and including HTML 4.01. In HTML5, it is permitted, but in HTML serialization, it means just `<title>`.

In genuine XHTML, i.e. in XHTML when delivered with an XML media type (rare on the web), `<title />` means the same as `<title></title>`. This is valid except according to HTML5 drafts, which require nonempty content here. But it is not recommended, because it does not work that way when a browser, or other program, processes the document as if it were in HTML syntax.

Cf. to [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)